# AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'set_schema_to_public' (tenat_schemas)

Tags: django, docker, heroku, multi-tenant

I am using Django+tenant_schemas, and my local version of my app works fine.  However, when I try to push it to staging (Heroku+Docker), I get the following error:

> **AttributeError:** 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute
>   'set_schema_to_public' (tenat_schemas).

The code points to:

```
tenant_schemas/middleware.py in process_request at line 46:

   connection.set_schema_to_public()
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error.  Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer this without more information, but the cause of your problem is probably that you're trying to use sqlite on Heroku. This error is thrown when you are trying to use the sqlite backend with the pgsql wrapper (or mysql). You should go through the [configuration guide for Django apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration) if you haven't already. If you post relevant sections from `settings.py` (with secrets removed, please!) and your Procfile it will be easier to give more help towards a solution.

Comment: You lead me to the correct answer.  It seems that my ENGINE was being overridden in my settings.py file. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem and I don't know how solve it. Can you tell me the steps to solve it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was that I had used `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2` instead of `django_tenants.postgresql_backend` for my database engine as instructed on the [docs](https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#basic-settings).

Answer (score 0):

i used this

DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql

then i got the this error
connection.set_schema(schema_name, tenant_type=tenant_type, include_public=False)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'set_schema'
then i update the  the database engine

DB_ENGINE=django_tenants.postgresql_backend

then this problem is solve by updating the code